# The Final Fantasy VIII leveling up problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

**1. Introduction**

In the video game Final Fantasy VIII, you control six characters. Each character starts the game with the following amount of experience points:

| Character | Initial EXP |
| --- | --- |
| $C_1$ | $6000$ |
| $C_2$ | $7000$ |
| $C_3$ | $7000$ |
| $C_4$ | $7000$ |
| $C_5$ | $10000$ |
| $C_6$ | $12000$ |

The **goal** is to engage in battles, win them and receive experience, until each character reaches $99000$ points.

**2. Rules**

The following rules must be observed:

**Rule 1:** Only three characters may engage in a battle at the same time. These are called active party members. The inactive party members do not receive experience points. The player can switch the group of active party members anytime between battles. $C_1$ is the group leader and *must always be active*.

**Rule 2:** Only two of the three active party members may receive experience points after winning a battle. The player can choose which characters receive the points. The leader $C_1$ may or may not receive experience, as the player decides.

**Rule 3:** One of the three active party members receives a bonus experience after winning a battle. The player decides which character receives the bonus points.

**3. Mechanics**

The amount of experience received after each battle is given by the formula:

$EXP=240\cdot(5\cdot (\dfrac{100-X}{X})+4)$

The variable $X$ stands for the average active party level. Considering $C_x$, $C_y$ and $C_z$ are the active party members, then:

$X=\dfrac{(C_x+C_y+C_z)}{3000}+1$

The amount of bonus experience received after each battle is given by the formula:

$BONUS=30\cdot(5\cdot (\dfrac{100-Y}{Y})+4)$

The variable $Y$ stands for the character level that earns the bonus points. Considering $C_x$ the character to receive the bonus, then:

$Y=\dfrac{C_x}{1000}+1$

**4. Example**

Since the amount of experience points the party receives after each battle lowers, as the characters earn more points, the general idea is to keep one or two low leveled characters in the active party, in order to boost the experience in each battle.

Another general idea is that, since the group leader $C_1$ may not be switched out, it is best to level him up last, so that he drags down the average party level as long as possible.

Quick example:

| Battles | EXP | Bonus | Member 1 | Member 2 | Member 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $C_1: 6000$ | $C_2: 7000$ | $C_3: 7000$ |
| $1$ | $16902$ | $1845$ to $C_2$ | $C_1: 6000$ | $C_2: 25747$ | $C_3: 23902$ |
| $2$ | $6075$ | $595$ to $C_2$ | $C_1: 6000$ | $C_2: 32417$ | $C_3: 29977$ |
| $3$ | $4977$ | $424$ to $C_2$ | $C_1: 6000$ | $C_2: 37818$ | $C_3: 34954$ |

Again, the player can change the active party members anytime, except for the group leader $C_1$.

Which is the minimum amount of battles required to complete the challenge?

Comment: Your formulas cannot be right.  Please proof-read.  For instance, if we have $C_x=6000$, $C_y=C_z=7000$, then $X=6667$ and then your formula says $EXP=-222$.  It makes no sense to say that they gain negative experience.  Please proof-read the question and [edit] it to make it correct.

Comment: Do both chosen players each receive $EXP$, or is $EXP$ split between the two chosen players? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I cannot spot the mistake. Using your example, the average party level would be $X=((6000+7000+7000)/3000)+1=6+1=7$. As for the EXP, both characters receive the same amount  of experience, they are not split.

Comment: $((6000+7000+7000)/3000) \not= 6$

Comment: In the game programmation, results are rounded down. So, $6.6...=6$.

Comment: Then shouldn't your $595$ instead be $546$?

Comment: Regarding "rounding down", you should explain your rules of arithmetic very carefully if you do not wish follow standard rules of arithmetic.

Comment: I also get $546$ for the bonus in round $2$, not $595$. Please clarify how you arrived at $595$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No proof of optimality, but I can do it in $116$ battles:
[image]

The bottom curve corresponds to the group leader.

Here's the full data:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Battle} & \text{X} & \text{Y} & \text{EXP} & \text{Bonus} & \text{Bonus To} & \text{Member 1} & \text{Member 2} & \text{Member 3} \\
\hline
1 & 7 & 8 & 16902 & 1845 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 23902 & C_3: 25747 \\
2 & 8 & 8 & 14760 & 1845 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 23605 & C_5: 24760 \\
3 & 14 & 13 & 8331 & 1123 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 31936 & C_6: 21454 \\
4 & 18 & 22 & 6426 & 651 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 30328 & C_6: 28531 \\
5 & 19 & 25 & 6075 & 570 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 31822 & C_5: 31405 \\
6 & 22 & 29 & 5214 & 487 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 35542 & C_6: 34232 \\
7 & 24 & 32 & 4760 & 438 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 36582 & C_5: 36603 \\
8 & 25 & 32 & 4560 & 438 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 36934 & C_6: 38792 \\
9 & 27 & 36 & 4204 & 386 & C_2 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 40132 & C_3: 40786 \\
10 & 27 & 37 & 4204 & 375 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 41138 & C_5: 41182 \\
11 & 29 & 39 & 3897 & 354 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 44029 & C_6: 43043 \\
12 & 30 & 41 & 3760 & 335 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 44881 & C_4: 44898 \\
13 & 31 & 42 & 3630 & 327 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_5: 45139 & C_6: 46673 \\
14 & 32 & 45 & 3510 & 303 & C_2 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 47842 & C_3: 48391 \\
15 & 33 & 45 & 3396 & 303 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 48597 & C_5: 48535 \\
16 & 34 & 47 & 3289 & 289 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 51131 & C_6: 50251 \\
17 & 35 & 49 & 3188 & 276 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 51855 & C_5: 51723 \\
18 & 35 & 49 & 3188 & 276 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 52061 & C_6: 53439 \\
19 & 37 & 52 & 3003 & 258 & C_2 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 54392 & C_5: 54726 \\
20 & 37 & 52 & 3003 & 258 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 55116 & C_4: 55064 \\
21 & 38 & 54 & 2917 & 247 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 57309 & C_6: 56603 \\
22 & 39 & 55 & 2836 & 242 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 57900 & C_5: 57804 \\
23 & 40 & 56 & 2760 & 237 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 58113 & C_6: 59363 \\
24 & 41 & 58 & 2686 & 228 & C_2 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 60223 & C_5: 60490 \\
25 & 41 & 58 & 2686 & 228 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 60799 & C_4: 60814 \\
26 & 42 & 60 & 2617 & 220 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 62840 & C_6: 62200 \\
27 & 43 & 61 & 2550 & 215 & C_5 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 63349 & C_5: 63255 \\
28 & 44 & 61 & 2487 & 215 & C_4 & C_1: 6000 & C_4: 63516 & C_6: 64687 \\
29 & 45 & 63 & 2426 & 208 & C_2 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 65474 & C_5: 65681 \\
30 & 45 & 64 & 2426 & 204 & C_3 & C_1: 6000 & C_3: 65979 & C_4: 65942 \\
31 & 46 & 65 & 2368 & 200 & C_6 & C_1: 6000 & C_2: 67842 & C_6: 67255 \\
32 & 46 & 7 & 2368 & 2112 & C_1 & C_1: 8112 & C_4: 68310 & C_5: 68049 \\
33 & 48 & 66 & 2260 & 197 & C_3 & C_1: 8112 & C_3: 68436 & C_6: 69515 \\
34 & 49 & 69 & 2208 & 187 & C_5 & C_1: 10320 & C_2: 70050 & C_5: 68236 \\
35 & 49 & 11 & 2208 & 1333 & C_1 & C_1: 11653 & C_4: 70518 & C_5: 70444 \\
36 & 50 & 12 & 2160 & 1220 & C_1 & C_1: 12873 & C_3: 70596 & C_6: 71675 \\
37 & 52 & 71 & 2067 & 181 & C_5 & C_1: 14940 & C_2: 72117 & C_5: 70625 \\
38 & 53 & 15 & 2024 & 970 & C_1 & C_1: 15910 & C_3: 72620 & C_4: 72542 \\
39 & 53 & 72 & 2024 & 178 & C_6 & C_1: 17934 & C_5: 72649 & C_6: 71853 \\
40 & 54 & 18 & 1982 & 803 & C_1 & C_1: 18737 & C_2: 74099 & C_6: 73835 \\
41 & 55 & 73 & 1941 & 175 & C_4 & C_1: 20678 & C_3: 72620 & C_4: 74658 \\
42 & 56 & 21 & 1902 & 684 & C_1 & C_1: 21362 & C_3: 74522 & C_5: 74551 \\
43 & 57 & 75 & 1865 & 170 & C_2 & C_1: 23227 & C_2: 74269 & C_6: 75700 \\
44 & 58 & 75 & 1828 & 170 & C_2 & C_1: 25055 & C_2: 76267 & C_3: 74522 \\
45 & 59 & 26 & 1793 & 546 & C_1 & C_1: 25601 & C_3: 76315 & C_5: 76344 \\
46 & 59 & 76 & 1793 & 167 & C_6 & C_1: 27394 & C_4: 76451 & C_6: 75867 \\
47 & 60 & 77 & 1760 & 164 & C_2 & C_1: 29154 & C_2: 76431 & C_6: 77627 \\
48 & 62 & 78 & 1695 & 162 & C_6 & C_1: 30849 & C_3: 78010 & C_6: 77789 \\
49 & 62 & 31 & 1695 & 453 & C_1 & C_1: 31302 & C_2: 78126 & C_5: 78039 \\
50 & 62 & 79 & 1695 & 159 & C_5 & C_1: 32997 & C_4: 78146 & C_5: 78198 \\
51 & 63 & 79 & 1664 & 159 & C_3 & C_1: 34661 & C_3: 78169 & C_6: 79453 \\
52 & 64 & 35 & 1635 & 398 & C_1 & C_1: 35059 & C_2: 79761 & C_4: 79781 \\
53 & 64 & 79 & 1635 & 159 & C_5 & C_1: 36694 & C_3: 79804 & C_5: 78357 \\
54 & 65 & 80 & 1606 & 157 & C_6 & C_1: 38300 & C_5: 79963 & C_6: 79610 \\
55 & 66 & 80 & 1578 & 157 & C_2 & C_1: 39878 & C_2: 79918 & C_6: 81188 \\
56 & 67 & 40 & 1551 & 345 & C_1 & C_1: 40223 & C_3: 81355 & C_4: 81332 \\
57 & 67 & 80 & 1551 & 157 & C_5 & C_1: 41774 & C_2: 81469 & C_5: 80120 \\
58 & 68 & 82 & 1524 & 152 & C_6 & C_1: 43298 & C_5: 81644 & C_6: 81340 \\
59 & 69 & 82 & 1499 & 152 & C_6 & C_1: 44797 & C_4: 81332 & C_6: 82991 \\
60 & 70 & 82 & 1474 & 152 & C_4 & C_1: 44797 & C_3: 82829 & C_4: 82958 \\
61 & 70 & 82 & 1474 & 152 & C_5 & C_1: 46271 & C_2: 82943 & C_5: 81796 \\
62 & 71 & 83 & 1450 & 150 & C_2 & C_1: 47721 & C_2: 83093 & C_5: 83246 \\
63 & 72 & 83 & 1426 & 150 & C_4 & C_1: 49147 & C_3: 84255 & C_4: 83108 \\
64 & 72 & 83 & 1426 & 150 & C_6 & C_1: 50573 & C_2: 84519 & C_6: 83141 \\
65 & 73 & 51 & 1403 & 264 & C_1 & C_1: 50837 & C_4: 84511 & C_6: 84544 \\
66 & 73 & 85 & 1403 & 146 & C_3 & C_1: 52240 & C_3: 84401 & C_5: 84649 \\
67 & 74 & 85 & 1381 & 146 & C_4 & C_1: 53621 & C_3: 85782 & C_4: 84657 \\
68 & 75 & 85 & 1360 & 146 & C_2 & C_1: 54981 & C_2: 86025 & C_6: 84544 \\
69 & 75 & 55 & 1360 & 242 & C_1 & C_1: 55223 & C_5: 86009 & C_6: 85904 \\
70 & 76 & 56 & 1338 & 237 & C_1 & C_1: 56798 & C_3: 85782 & C_4: 85995 \\
71 & 77 & 86 & 1318 & 144 & C_6 & C_1: 58116 & C_3: 87100 & C_6: 86048 \\
72 & 77 & 87 & 1318 & 142 & C_5 & C_1: 59434 & C_4: 87313 & C_5: 86151 \\
73 & 78 & 60 & 1298 & 220 & C_1 & C_1: 59654 & C_2: 87323 & C_6: 87346 \\
74 & 78 & 87 & 1298 & 142 & C_5 & C_1: 60952 & C_3: 87100 & C_5: 87591 \\
75 & 79 & 88 & 1278 & 140 & C_3 & C_1: 62230 & C_3: 88518 & C_4: 87313 \\
76 & 79 & 88 & 1278 & 140 & C_4 & C_1: 63508 & C_2: 88601 & C_4: 87453 \\
77 & 80 & 88 & 1260 & 140 & C_6 & C_1: 64768 & C_4: 88713 & C_6: 87486 \\
78 & 80 & 65 & 1260 & 200 & C_1 & C_1: 64968 & C_5: 88851 & C_6: 88746 \\
79 & 81 & 89 & 1241 & 138 & C_3 & C_1: 66209 & C_2: 88601 & C_3: 89897 \\
80 & 82 & 89 & 1223 & 138 & C_2 & C_1: 67432 & C_2: 89962 & C_4: 88713 \\
81 & 82 & 68 & 1223 & 190 & C_1 & C_1: 67622 & C_4: 89936 & C_6: 89969 \\
82 & 83 & 89 & 1205 & 138 & C_5 & C_1: 68827 & C_3: 89897 & C_5: 90194 \\
83 & 83 & 90 & 1205 & 136 & C_3 & C_1: 70032 & C_3: 91238 & C_4: 89936 \\
84 & 84 & 90 & 1188 & 136 & C_4 & C_1: 71220 & C_2: 89962 & C_4: 91260 \\
85 & 84 & 72 & 1188 & 178 & C_1 & C_1: 72586 & C_2: 89962 & C_6: 91157 \\
86 & 85 & 90 & 1171 & 136 & C_2 & C_1: 72586 & C_2: 91269 & C_5: 91365 \\
87 & 85 & 92 & 1171 & 133 & C_6 & C_1: 73757 & C_3: 91238 & C_6: 92461 \\
88 & 86 & 92 & 1155 & 133 & C_3 & C_1: 74912 & C_3: 92526 & C_4: 91260 \\
89 & 86 & 92 & 1155 & 133 & C_4 & C_1: 76067 & C_2: 92424 & C_4: 91393 \\
90 & 87 & 77 & 1139 & 164 & C_1 & C_1: 76231 & C_4: 92532 & C_5: 92504 \\
91 & 88 & 77 & 1123 & 164 & C_1 & C_1: 77518 & C_2: 93547 & C_5: 92504 \\
92 & 88 & 93 & 1123 & 131 & C_6 & C_1: 78641 & C_5: 92504 & C_6: 93715 \\
93 & 88 & 93 & 1123 & 131 & C_3 & C_1: 79764 & C_3: 92657 & C_5: 93627 \\
94 & 89 & 80 & 1108 & 157 & C_1 & C_1: 79921 & C_3: 93765 & C_4: 93640 \\
95 & 90 & 80 & 1093 & 157 & C_1 & C_1: 81171 & C_2: 94640 & C_5: 93627 \\
96 & 90 & 94 & 1093 & 129 & C_5 & C_1: 82264 & C_4: 93640 & C_5: 94849 \\
97 & 90 & 94 & 1093 & 129 & C_4 & C_1: 83357 & C_4: 93769 & C_6: 94808 \\
98 & 91 & 94 & 1078 & 129 & C_3 & C_1: 84435 & C_3: 93894 & C_4: 94847 \\
99 & 91 & 95 & 1078 & 127 & C_2 & C_1: 85513 & C_2: 94767 & C_3: 94972 \\
100 & 92 & 95 & 1064 & 127 & C_2 & C_1: 86577 & C_2: 94894 & C_6: 95872 \\
101 & 93 & 95 & 1050 & 127 & C_5 & C_1: 87627 & C_4: 95897 & C_5: 94976 \\
102 & 93 & 88 & 1050 & 140 & C_1 & C_1: 87767 & C_2: 95944 & C_3: 96022 \\
103 & 93 & 96 & 1050 & 126 & C_6 & C_1: 88817 & C_5: 96026 & C_6: 95998 \\
104 & 94 & 96 & 1036 & 126 & C_2 & C_1: 89853 & C_2: 96070 & C_4: 96933 \\
105 & 94 & 90 & 1036 & 136 & C_1 & C_1: 89989 & C_3: 97058 & C_6: 97034 \\
106 & 95 & 97 & 1023 & 124 & C_5 & C_1: 91012 & C_2: 97093 & C_5: 96150 \\
107 & 95 & 97 & 1023 & 124 & C_4 & C_1: 92035 & C_4: 97057 & C_5: 97173 \\
108 & 96 & 98 & 1010 & 123 & C_4 & C_1: 93045 & C_4: 97180 & C_6: 98044 \\
109 & 96 & 98 & 1010 & 123 & C_2 & C_1: 94055 & C_2: 97216 & C_3: 98068 \\
110 & 97 & 95 & 997 & 127 & C_1 & C_1: 94182 & C_4: 98177 & C_5: 98170 \\
111 & 97 & 95 & 997 & 127 & C_1 & C_1: 95306 & C_2: 98213 & C_6: 98044 \\
112 & 98 & 99 & 984 & 121 & C_3 & C_1: 96290 & C_3: 98189 & C_6: 99028 \\
113 & 98 & 99 & 984 & 121 & C_4 & C_1: 97274 & C_4: 98298 & C_5: 99154 \\
114 & 98 & 98 & 984 & 123 & C_1 & C_1: 97397 & C_2: 99197 & C_3: 99173 \\
115 & 99 & 98 & 972 & 123 & C_1 & C_1: 98492 & C_4: 99270 & C_6: 99028 \\
116 & 99 & 100 & 972 & 120 & C_5 & C_1: 99464 & C_5: 99274 & C_6: 100000 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
The approach I used is a sequence of nonlinear programming problems, with a "diving" heuristic that fixes one binary decision variable to $1$ at each step.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you explain the strategy you used? Do you level up two characters at the same time three times or do you keep switching characters to ensure the lowest average level each battle?